# vm copied by veeam but I can't see it on vmware

Tags: vmware-esxi, veeam

I copied a vmware virtual machine by veeam 6.1. with "vm copy" task.
Veeam is installed on a vm together with vsphere client over a vmware physical host.
Now I want modify or start the vm I have copied but I cannot see it on vsphere. How can I say to vmware that there is one more vm ?

Answer (score 0):

Late reply, but can you see the VM on the datastore where you copied it to? If so - all you need to do is add it to the inventory.

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1006160